# how to make calculations in SQL server?

Tags: sql-server

How to make calculation in SQL server?
There are two tables I have join them and i need to insert a new column that Will make a calculation for me.
This is a small project for my course please help me.
[There are two tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EGzHX.png)
[This is how I need it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yuWiq.png)

Comment: Did you even try to do anything? This is very basic SQL.

Comment: i cant write in the box it says only one

Comment: how to write the code in the box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a really simple query and shows a lack of effort on your part...

```
select /* columns... */
  , f.[number of films]*(100.0-r.discount) as price
from [number of films bought] f
  inner join [date of registration] r
    on f.id = r.id
```

Comment: @ArouvenArouPoolian You do not need a function for this calculation, using `f.[number of films]*(100.0-r.discount) as price` performs the calculation and returns the value as a column named `price`.. If you must create and use a function for your assignment, I suggest you look here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/user-defined-functions/create-user-defined-functions-database-engine

Comment: @ArouvenArouPoolian I apologize, I just can't bring myself to do your homework for you any more than I already have... Try this: [Create User-defined Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/user-defined-functions/create-user-defined-functions-database-engine)

Comment: We really shouldn't be writing code for people who have shown no effort already.